# Uable to declare a char string properly in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int i, j,
      matriz[4][4] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, l, c,
      matrizcontrolo[4][4] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      ponto = 0, ntentativa = 0;
  const char array1[4][4] = {"0000", "0000", "0000", "0000"};
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    do {
      printf("Tentativa %d\n", ntentativa + 1);
      do {
        printf("Linha:\n");

        scanf("%d", &l);
      } while (l < 1 || l > 4);
      do {
        printf("Coluna:\n");
        scanf("%d", &c);
      } while (c < 1 || c > 4);
    } while (matrizcontrolo[l][c] == 1);
    if (matriz[l - 1][c - 1] == 0) {
      printf("Splash!\n");
      strcpy(array1[l - 1][c - 1], "x");
    } else {
      printf("Boom!\n");
      ponto = ponto + 2;
      i--;
      strcpy(array1[l - 1][c - 1], "S");
    }
    matrizcontrolo[l][c] = 1;
    ntentativa++;
  }
  printf("O campo de batalha foi\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s ", *array1[i]);
  }
  if (ponto == 8) {
    printf("Parabéns, acertou em todos os barcos e a sua pontuação foi de %d",
           ponto);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I receive an error which states:

main.c:31:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
/usr/include/string.h:129:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
main.c:37:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
/usr/include/string.h:129:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
main.c:45:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

And then it just simply:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

When I try to run the program by inserting values in the matriz variable.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad news is you're using `strcpy` wrong. The good news is you don't need to use it anyway.

Fyi, [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) requires a non-const target buffer sufficient to store the source string you're copying, and including one additional spot for the terminating nullchar. you're targeting a single `char`, not a `char*`

Additionally, your string buffers are *all* undersized. A string `"0000"` requires **five** characters for storage: four of the string, plus one for the terminating nullchar.

Finally, the string buffer array cannot be `const`. You're going to be changing data in those rows.

This code shouldn't be using `strcpy` *anywhere*. All you're really trying to do is set specific characters in terminated string to specific values. C provides a way to do that: *assignment*. A modified version of your program is below. I cannot attest to whether the game play is correct or not, but it addresses the specific issue you're having regarding your reported errors, and shows you how direct cell-assignment is what you're really after.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, l, c, ponto = 0, ntentativa = 0;

    int matriz[][4] = {
        {0, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
        {1, 1, 0, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    int matrizcontrolo[][4] = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
        
    char array1[][5] = {
        "0000", 
        "0000", 
        "0000", 
        "0000"
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Tentativa %d\n", ntentativa + 1);
            do
            {
                printf("Linha:\n");
                scanf("%d", &l);
            } while (l < 1 || l > 4);
            do
            {
                printf("Coluna:\n");
                scanf("%d", &c);
            } while (c < 1 || c > 4);
        } while (matrizcontrolo[l][c] == 1);

        if (matriz[l - 1][c - 1] == 0)
        {
            printf("Splash!\n");
            array1[l-1][c-1] = 'x';
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Boom!\n");
            ponto = ponto + 2;
            i--;
            array1[l - 1][c - 1]= 'S';
        }
        matrizcontrolo[l][c] = 1;
        ntentativa++;
    }

    printf("O campo de batalha foi\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        puts(array1[i]);
    }

    if (ponto == 8)
    {
        printf("Parabéns, acertou em todos os barcos e a sua pontuação foi de %d",
               ponto);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alas, your code also produces a Segmentation fault after printing the array1 in the last cycle...

Comment: I've isolated the cause of the segmentation fault: it's this line of code ``` matrizcontrolo[l][c] = 1; ``` If comment this line the error disappears...Any idea about what's causing it?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug in the original code. That should be `matrizcontrolo[l-1][c-1] = 1;` Fyi ,the same bug is in the first do-loop, which should be `} while (matrizcontrolo[l-1][c-1] == 1);` See what happens when you fight against zero-based indexing?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not sure what exactly is the logic and goal behind your program. But the problems are clear, and they all are solvable:

1. In this syntax:

   ```
   strcpy(array1[l - 1][c - 1], "x");
   ```

   When you access the two-dimensional array with two subscript operators, it is no longer referred to as a pointer, but the type `char`. Whereas, the `strcpy()` asks you the following parameter:

   ```
   char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
   ```

   You need to pass `array1[]` (char*), not `array1[][]` (char). In simple, you don't need `strcpy()` function:

   ```
   array[l - 1][c - 1] = 'x';
   ```
2. You don't have sufficient rooms in the defined two-dimensional array. There is always a null-terminated character that is put at the end of each string. Thus, instead of providing 4 for `0000`, increase it by one, i.e. 5, and similarly with others that are a type of `char[]` or `char[][]`.
3. In the following statement:

   ```
   matriz[4][4] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   ```

   You're initializing the 2-D array in an incorrect way. You need to make it with nested-braces:

   ```
   matriz[4][4] = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
   ```

   Do the same with `matrizcontrolo[][]`.
4. You need not put an asterisk to dereference this:

   ```
   printf("%s ", *array1[i]);
                 ^^^___ remove the asterisk
   ```

Comment: Re 1.:Passing `array1[]` to `strcpy` would be syntactically correct, but not do what is intented. Just assigning `'X'` to `array1[][]` would do the trick.

Comment: @Gerhardh yep, I've clarified that now.